# Adding zip code to search option with theme/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, search, directory-listing

I am currently trying to use "listingpro" theme which is a listing directory. There is a search function which cities can be used to search for listings within a chosen radius. The admin has to put in the cities for each of the listings and the search results will appear on the map using google maps api.

However, using zipcodes for search options is not an option. I am wondering if there is some way in which I can add searching by zip code feature so when a user types in their zip code the listings within the designated radius will appear on the search page and on the map. Or if there is a tutorial somewhere on how to do this? This is a bit over my head and I am not sure if this is possible with this theme without doing a ton of customizing. 
Thank a lot for your input!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://docs.listingprowp.com/faq/does-listingpro-also-has-search-results-by-zip-code/), this is possible with the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). I assume the theme uses Google Maps API as default, so switching out or adding the the GPAPI would require a fair amount of customization.